# Java Spring app takes long time to start on brand new MacBook Pro M3

Tags: java, macos, performance

I have brand new MacBook Pro M3 32GB. I'm using Intellij Ultimate (for Apple silicon) and I'm trying different JDKs for both Gradle and Project Setup. From Correto JDK 17 to OpenJDK 21. All of them designed for Apple silicion, so it's aarch64.

I have quite small Spring Boot project running, I'm pressing run and then it freezes on attached console output, [image]

Then, after few seconds, Spring Boot logs shows up and according to them, app starts in less than 1 second.

Now what is strage, is that yesterday I simply rebooted OS and then there was no lag at all, from pressing "run" to actually running app it took around 1.5 second. With this lag it takes around 8 seconds, and rebooting OS is not helping anymore.

Any ideas what may be wrong with this setup? I'm sure that both JDK and Intelij is in correct, not Intel version.

Comment: I don't see anything unusual with your setup and I don't see any general M3 issues in the Jetbrains issue tracker.  How's life if you try this in Safe Mode?  I might think you've got something else installed that may be eating resources considering some success you had rebooting.